Guidelines for larger wheel (rubber) compared to rim to avoid rim scratches while parking
On summer tires I have 235/35-R19 tires mounted on 8J-19 rims. Since 8 * 25.4 = 203.2 mm, this means that the rubber protrudes on either side by (235 - 203.2) / 2 = 15.9 mm.
You'd think that ~16 mm is a lot, but in practice it is, and it looks, quite little. One mistake out of a few hundred times while parallel parking, and I'll have scratched a rim.
While looking for winter tires, I'm contemplating installing 205/45-R17 on 7.5J-17. This is one of the official offerings from the dealership, but I'd still like to evaluate (understand) what's happening. Converting I get 7.5 * 25.4 = 190.5 mm, which means I'd have just (205 - 190.5) / 2 = 7.25 mm of rubber protruding on each side.

Is this the correct way to calculate how much the rubber will protrude?
Is there a guideline for how much larger the rubber should be compared to the rim?


If you have remote control mirrors, use them to point down for parking. You'll see how far you are from the curb. BMW does it automatically when backing up in their '24 iX ev suv.

@FDryer Parking is just an example (there is, anyway, parking assist). But on principle, would you choose rim + tires that make the tire extend just 7 mm past the rim on each side?

Personally, no. I find it easier but a little tedious, to remotely rotate the right side mirror down to see the curb when backing up for parallel parking. Not all the time. I learn to use whatever sight lines on front and rear corners and a picture in my mind where the tires should be near curbs. I'm not immune to mistakes with a new cuv Subaru and ran over a few round curbs , turning in too early in parking lots but haven't scratched my rims yet.
